# not able to get new session java web project

Tags: java, session, netbeans

I am using NetBeans to create a java web application. I have used only jsp to create the project.

I want to provide login functionality. So, I need to work with `Session`.

I have tried to get session info on the very next page after the login page.
Meaning that login.jsp is the page where I ask user to give login details. And the next page is verifyCredentials.jsp where I am verifying credentials and checking for new session.

But every time I am getting old session only. So I am not able to get new session for the first login also.

I have tried sample code from [Check session](http://javaj2eepro.blogspot.in/2011/04/14-simple-project-to-check-session.html) to check the functionality of session but it is also taking old session every time.

Getting same problem with every browser.

NetBeans version is 7.2.1 and JDK is 1.7

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: Avoid implementing security access in JSPs, even more, avoid to write any Java code in JSPs. For a reliable loging approach, read about [security in Java Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html)

Comment: yep, I know that java code should not be implemented in jsps.. but as most off the project is done in jsp only. now i dont have enough time to change whole code and use MVC architecture. :-)

FOllowing is the link from where I tried the demo.
http://javaj2eepro.blogspot.in/2011/04/14-simple-project-to-check-session.html